Three-player Avalon (transmitting private knowledge over a public channel)
Players

There are a total of three players, split into two teams:

Team Resistance has two players whose roles are assigned at the start of the game.
Team Spy has one player (the Spy).



Before starting the game

Both Resistance players must agree on the Strategy they will follow during the game. The Spy must be made aware of this Strategy. Neither Resistance players can deviate from this Strategy during the game.
The Spy does not need to reveal their strategy as a Spy.

At the start of the game

Roles

One of the Resistance players is assigned the role Merlin and the other Resistance player is assigned the role Vanilla. Both assignments happen with 50% probability.
Merlin knows who is Vanilla and who is Spy. Vanilla knows who is Merlin and who is Spy. Spy does not know who is Merlin and who is Vanilla.


Secret

A variable called Secret is generated. Secret is 0 with 50% probability and 1 with 50% probability.
Merlin knows the Secret. Spy knows the Secret. Vanilla does not know the Secret.



During the game

There is a blackboard in public view of all players
The blackboard starts empty.
Merlin and Vanilla can write on the blackboard as per the rules below. Spy can observe the blackboard but cannot write on it.
On timestep T, both Resistance players simultaneously write a Word each on the blackboard, or they can write STOP. Neither player can see what the other player is writing during a timestep until both players finish writing their respective Words for a given timestep.

This Word can depend on the state of the blackboard state until (and including) timestep T-1, and the role who is writing it.
A Word can including English words, numbers or other characters.
Both players are allowed to generate random numbers in their head as part of their Strategy.
Neither player is allowed to write down encryption keys on the whiteboard.



Ending the game

If a Resistance player writes STOP, this player must make a guess of what Secret is. If both players write STOP on the same timestep, one player is picked at random (50% probability each) and is asked to make a guess of what Secret is.
If this guess is incorrect, the Resistance team loses.
If this guess is correct, the Spy must guess which of the Resistance players is Merlin.
If the Spy guesses correctly, the Resistance team loses. Else the Resistance team wins.

The puzzle
Suggest a Strategy that maximises the Resistance team's expected probability of winning, assuming optimal play by the Spy.

What qualifies as an encryption key for the rule, "Neither player is allowed to write down encryption keys on the whiteboard." Is it just numbers over a certain size that are banned, or do the rule prohibit using any object that was written on the board for encryption? (In the latter case, the puzzle is almost certainly impossible)

Just to check I understand the rules correctly: let $p$ be the expected probability of the Resistance winning, then $$37.5%\le p \le 50%,$$ because $p\ge 3/8$ since the Strategy of "both write STOP on T=1 and guess randomly if selected to guess as Vanilla (and guess correctly if selected to guess as Merlin)" guesses correctly with probability $3/4$ then loses to the Spy guess with half chance, while $p\le 1/2$ as the Spy has the strategy of "ignore everything and randomly guess the Merlin".

@BenjaminWang - The spy can do slightly better in that strategy by guessing that whomever answered is Merlin. If Norm answers, there is a 50% chance to get it wrong - meaning that half of Norm's games will never proceed to the spy's guess, while all of Merlin's will. This improves the spy's odds to 2/3, so $p \ge 1/4$.

Thank you for pointing that out, so $$25% \le p \le 50%.$$

For the encryption key rule, it seems like the intent is to disallow solutions where the players write down their public keys and then transmit RSA-encoded messages. If that interpretation is correct, I'd suggest changing the rule to "the spy has infinite computing power (and thus can brute-force any encryption)", which should be an unambiguous way to impose that restriction.

Are solution that involve qubits allowed? I'm guessing no but asking to make sure.

If A writes "1" on the blackboard and B writes "STOP", does B see the "1" before making their guess?

Would doing something like Blum's coin flip algorithm ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239202/how-to-perform-a-fair-coin-toss-experiment-over-phone ) break the "no encryption keys" rule? After Merlin and Norm have both factored numbers, they write a message like "if larger factor is 3 mod 4, secret is 1; otherwise 0"  (Under Carmeister's interpretation, no.)

@ralphmerridew The Spy must be made aware of this Strategy and can theoretically brute-force to find the secret.

Building on Tim C's answer, I propose that we can get arbitrarily close to:

 $\frac13$.

Consider the following strategy:
Merlin writes 'STOP' with probability $ε>0$, and otherwise writes 'Pelican'. Vanilla writes 'STOP' with probability $2ε$, and otherwise writes 'Pelican'. Thus, at each timestep, we have the following probabilities:

P(Two pelicans, go again) = $(1 - ε)(1 - 2ε)$
P(Merlin writes STOP, guesses correctly) = $ε(1 - 2ε)$
P(Vanilla writes STOP, guesses correctly) = $ε(1 - ε)$
P(Vanilla writes STOP, guesses wrong) = $ε(1 - ε)$
P(Both write STOP) = $2ε^2$

The probability of terminating on this timestep is $q:=1 - (1 - ε) * (1 - 2ε)$.

Resistance obviously lose if Vanilla guesses wrong.
If exactly one player writes STOP, then Vanilla is marginally more likely to give a correct answer than Merlin, so Spy should guess Vanilla. So

Vanilla guessing right is a loss,
Merlin giving the correct answer is a win.


Two stops is a 1 in 4 chance - Spy should guess Merlin, so we need Vanilla to answer correctly.

So the probability of Resistance winning on this timestep is $p:=ε(1 - 2ε) + ε^2/2$. Intuitively, the victory probability is
$$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{ε - 3ε^2/2}{3ε - 2ε^2} = \frac{1 - 3ε/2}{3 - 2ε}$$
As $ε$ tends to $0$, this tends to $\frac13$, so we can get arbitrarily close by picking a sufficiently small value for $ε$ (and writing a lot of pelicans).
Mathematical technicality:

 Technically we computed $$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{P(\text{win on }T_1)}{P(\text{term. on }T_1)}$$ but we are interested in $r:=P(\text{win})$ itself. This can either be calculated with a geometric series or the first-step conditioning recursion $$P(\text{win}) = P(\text{win on }T_1) + P(\text{win later})$$ noting that $P(\text{win later}) = P(\text{no term. on }T_1)P(\text{win})$, giving $$r=p+(1-q)r$$ and therefore $r=p/q$ as per intuition.


Upper Bound
I propose that no possible strategy can achieve a win-rate for the Resistance higher than

 $\frac13$.

Proof
There are four possible states of the game (excluding the Spy's guess):

Merlin answers correctly.
Merlin answers incorrectly.
Norm answers correctly.
Norm answers incorrectly.

The upper bound is reached when the following is true:

 Outcome 1, 3, and 4 are all equally likely. Outcome 2 never happens.
 In Outcome 4, the Resistance loses. In outcomes 1 and 3, the Spy guesses randomly and wins 50% of the time.

Lemma 1: Norm must guess randomly
An encryption key is:

A piece of information.... which, when processed through a cryptographic algorithm, can encode or decode cryptographic data

Cryptography is

the practice and study of techniques for secure communication in the presence of adversarial behavior

Since the Resistance is not allowed to use encryption keys, this means that they are by definition unable to secure their communication. If they were able to secure their communication using a strategy, then that strategy would be a cryptographic algorithm (by definition). Any artifact such as a random number which the Resistance creates during play for the purpose of securing their communication be a cryptographic key (also by definition), and would therefore be illegal to transmit.
Given that: Suppose that a strategy exists where Merlin transmits the secret to Norm.
This strategy must be symmetric; if Norm does not also transmit something to Merlin at the same time, under the same protocol, the Spy can deduce Merlin's identity from the exchange (with 100% certainty). If Norm does transmit something, then this transmitted data has a 50% chance of corresponding to the secret and a 50% chance of diverging. If it diverges, then the Spy (who knows the secret already) can deduce Norm's identity from the exchange, and they can then discover Merlin by isolation.
This means that any strategy where Merlin transmits the secret has at least a 50% chance of exposing Merlin's identity. If Merlin's identity is not exposed, then they can still guess randomly and be correct 50% of the time.
Thus, a strategy where Merlin transmits the secret cannot have a success rate above $\frac14$.
Random strategies including transmission
Suppose that the secret is 1 and Merlin transmits with probability $t$.
Merlin has a $t$ chance of transmitting 1, a $\frac{1-t}2$ chance of writing 1 randomly, and a $\frac{1-t}2$ chance of writing 0 randomly, for a total $\frac{t + 1}2$ chance of writing 1 and $\frac{1 - t}2$ chance of writing 0 randomly.
Norm has a 50% chance of writing 1 randomly and a 50% chance of writing 0 randomly.
Then each player has a 50% chance of being chosen to answer correctly.
Merlin answers correctly always. Norm answers correctly if and only if Merlin wrote 1.



Row
Merlin
Norm
Answered By
Correct?
Probability




1
$1$
$1$
Merlin
Yes
$\frac{t+1}8$


2
$1$
$1$
Norm
Yes
$\frac{t+1}8$


3
$1$
$0$
Merlin
Yes
$\frac{t+1}8$


4
$1$
$0$
Norm
Yes
$\frac{t+1}8$


5
$0$
$1$
Merlin
Yes
$\frac{1-t}8$


6
$0$
$1$
Norm
No
$\frac{1-t}8$


7
$0$
$0$
Merlin
Yes
$\frac{1-t}8$


8
$0$
$0$
Norm
No
$\frac{1-t}8$



Strategies of this form cannot achieve a score above $\frac14$.
First, look at the rows 3 and 7. Here, Merlin answered correctly, but Merlin's answer was different from Norm's answer. These situations could never occur if the positions were reversed, so the Spy can immediately identify Merlin.
This leaves the Resistance only having a chance to win in rows 1, 2, 4, and 5.
The sum of the probabilities of these 4 rows is $\frac{t + 2}4$.
The sum of the remaining rows where Merlin answered is $\frac14$ (this makes sense, as Norm has a 50% chance of coincidentally transmitting the correct answer), while the sum of the rows where Norm answered is $\frac{t + 1}4$.
This means that for all $t \gt 0$, the Spy should guess whomever did not answer as Merlin (when Merlin's identity cannot be otherwise deduced), leaving the Resistance with a total of $\frac14$ chance of winning for all strategies of this form, regardless of the value of $t$.
Lemma 2: Merlin must answer correctly exactly as often as Norm
Let $M$ be the statement "The person who answered is Merlin," $N$ be the statement, "The person who answered is Norm," and $C$ be the statement, "The person who answered, answered correctly." Define $P(k)$ as the probability of $k$ is true, and $P(k|n)$ as the probability that $k$ is true given that $n$ is true.
Because the Spy knows the Resistance's strategy, the spy can calculate $P(M|C)$ and $P(N|C)$. By choosing whichever is more likely and guessing Merlin based on that, the spy can set the Resistance's odds of winning to be $P(C) * \min(P(M|C), P(N|C))$. This function has a maximum when $P(M|C) = P(N|C)$.
Thus, assuming that the Resistance's strategy does not leak any other information, the optimal strategy must be one where a correct answer is equally likely to have been produced by either player.
Putting it together
Since the probability of outcome 3 equals the probability of outcome 4 (by Lemma 1) and the probability of outcome 1 equals the probability of outcome 3 (by lemma 2), no strategy can beat one where the probabilities of all three of these values are equal.
A strategy which has these properties would have a success rate of $\frac13$ which cannot be improved.
(Lack of) Construction
I am not aware of any strategy where Merlin can answer less often than Norm without leaking any information to the Spy. I believe that such a strategy is impossible (and that the Resistance's actual best odds are $\frac14$), but I cannot prove this yet.

What if Merlin transmits the secret correctly with probability $p$, $1/2<p<1$? In lemma 1 you considered the case $p=1$ and showed that it gives only a 1/4 chance of winning, and the case $p=1/2$ gives the 1/3 chance since it is equivalent to Merlin and Norm exchanging no information at all. Is it possible that a $p$ somewhere in between actually gives a better winning chance though?

Also, it's definitely possible for Norm and Merlin to answer with different probabilities - Norm can randomly choose to write "answer" or "don't answer" with respective probabilities p and q, while Merlin does so with probabilities P and Q. They repeat until they write different things, and then the one who wrote "answer" writes "STOP" next. The ratio pQ/qP is the odds that Norm answers vs Merlin.

the spy can set the Resistance's odds of winning to be P(C)-max(P(M|C),P(N|C)) I believe it should be P(C)*(1-max(P(M|C),P(N|C))), given that Spy only takes a guess if Resistance guessed right. (This does not affect the rest of the reasoning).

@Carmeister - I've added a section which I believe proves that having a probability-to-transmit can't do better than $\frac14$, because the Spy can derive some information from the attempted transmission. I think your proposed strategy of writing "answer" and "don't answer" is the optimal strategy.

@UJM - Thanks, fixed. Also (1-max(P(M|C),P(N|C))) is equal to min(P(M|C),P(N|C)) so I made that simplification as well. I think it makes the logic easier to follow to do so.
